# Exporting data from one excel sheet into a new excel sheet using Microsoft Office apps 2013

Tags: office-2013

Im facing a problem with Task Pane control of Microsoft Office Apps 2013, I've created an Office 2013 App wherein im writing data on the excel using the office app and reading back from it. This is working fine, but now I want the values read from the current excel sheet into another new excel sheet. Now I've written a code to do this from some references on the internet using javascript and it works on the browser. But im not able to get it to work on the app.
It'll probably work if I get the current instance of the excelsheet in working on, but I don't know how to get that either. im attaching the javascript code along with this post.
One more thing, when I open the app in excel it shows the following error message
An add-on for the website failed to run. Check the security settings in internet options. I tried changing the settings in internet options and set everything to enabled. still im getting this error.
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

```
var MyArray = [['Berlin'],['Munich'],['Duisburg']];
function writeToExcel() {
    var i, j, str;  
    var   myTable = MyArray;    
    alert(myTable.length);      
    var   rowCount = myTable.length;
    var  excel = new ActiveXObject('Excel.Application');// Activates Excel          
    excel.Visible = true;
    excel.Workbooks.Add(); // Opens a new Workbook
    excel.Application.Visible = true; // Shows Excel on the screen
    var i=0
    myTable.forEach(
        function(item) 
        {
            alert(item) 
            excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1).Value = item; // Writes to the sheet
            i=i+1;
        }
    );
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know, the Javascript API don't support to create new sheet.
You can reference the following link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/appsforoffice/thread/01c75559-a591-4d2b-a0ea-24103cdea1d5